# If $\gcd(n,|a|)=1$, prove that $C(a)=C(a^n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This question was actually asked in two parts.

Part 1: Show that $C(a) \subseteq C(a^n)$ for $n\geq1$.

I proved Part 1 like this: $$ay=ya, y\in G
\\a^{n-1}ay=a^{n-1}ya
\\a^ny=yaa^{n-1}, \text{by assumption}\ ay=ya
\\a^ny=ya^n$$

Part 2: If $\gcd(n,|a|)=1$, prove that $C(a)=C(a^n)$.

This part is what's giving me trouble. I don't see how either statements are connected to each other? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: Thinking about it for a bit more, I realized that I can keep Part 1's proof to show $C(a) \subseteq C(a^n)$. Now all I need to show is $C(a^n) \subseteq C(a)$ given $\gcd(n,|a|)=1$.

Attempt:
Let $|a|=m$ where $\gcd(n,m)=1$.
Then there exists two integers $k$ and $t$ such that $nk+mt=1$.
It follows that $mt\equiv1\mod{n}$.
So, we have $ya=ya^{mt}=a^mya^{m(t-1)}...=a^{mt}y=ay$.

Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show $C(a^n) \subset C(a)$, note that if $y a^n = a^n y$, since $\gcd (n, |a|) = 1$ we have some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $(a^n)^k = a^{nk} = a$. Thus we get $y a = y (a^n)^k = (a^n)^k y = a y$.

To see the claim about the gcd, note that we have some integers $k, l$ such that $k n + l |a| = 1$. Thus $(a^n)^k = a^{nk} = a^{1 - l |a|} = a a^{-l |a|} = a (a^{|a|})^{-l} = a$

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited an attempt at the proof moments ago, and what you posted makes me feel like I got the right idea. Would you mind checking if my Part 2 proof is missing anything?

Comment: Looks correct to me!

Comment: Yay! :D Thank you once again!